# How to examine stack frames in intellij IDEA python plugin debugger execution is paused?

Tags: python, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm trying to debug a script in intellij run as follows:

```
Run > Edit Configurations
> script: cmd.py
Run > Debug
```

which executes:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/xxx/.IdeaIC15/config/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 38268 --file ./cmd.py     
pydev debugger: process 14662 is connecting
Connected to pydev debugger (build 143.1184)
```

I hit pause in the debugger.
At this point the execution has stopped. But there is no frame drop down or icon in the debugger window in which the stack can be examined.

Python 2.7.6, IDEA 15.0.2, Python Community Edition plugin (5.0.143)

Answer (score 2):

maybe "Frames" panel is set to zero width.

(IDEA 14:)

View (main menu) -> Tool Windows -> Debug.

If You now see "Debug" window, with "Debugger" and "Console" tabs, and if in "Debugger" tab You can't find "Frames" panel, nor "Frames" icon in upper right corner or "Debug" window, try to drag "Variables"' left edge (or "Watches"', if You don't see "Variables" panel) to the right.

Comment: Thanks, I found the "Frame Panel" finally. And this picture may help: http://imgur.com/a/SWq1d